# If Statement--related with making integers in percentages of other integers

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to write an if statement where I return the string "Close String"  when int d is within 10% of int e. This is what I have now:

```
public String game(double d, double e) {
    if((d>=.95*e)||(d<=e*1.05)) {
       return "close string";
    } else {
       return "other";
    }
}
```

**TEST CASE**

```
    String game = game(100.0d, 90.0d);
    System.out.println(game);
    game = game(100.0d, 99.0d);
    System.out.println(game);
    game = game(100.0d, 100.0d);
    System.out.println(game);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
other
close string
close string
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
close string
close string
close string
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is `b` undeclare variable?

Comment: what is b?, not even defined in the function, are you sure it even compiles?

Comment: how can someone not see a question here, which was answered by the way? :P

Comment: because `(d>=.95*e)||(d<=e*1.05)` is always TRUE;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I think you want and instead of or.

```
(a>=.95*b)||(a<=b*1.05)
```

a can then be any number, because it will be less than 5% above b, or 5% below b as long as it is a real number.

```
(a>=.95*b)&&(a<=b*1.05)
```

a can only be within + or - 5%